# Convert feet to CM

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    Name                  Team      Number  Position    Age    Height   Weight  College           Salary
1   Jae Crowder     Boston Celtics  99.0    SF          25.0    6-6      235.0  Marquette       6796117.0
2   John Holland    Boston Celtics  30.0    SG  2       7.0      6-5     205.0  Boston University   NaN
```

Hi, I have this table and I want to convert the Height from feet to CM in new column, the height column RN isn't float neither int so I need to extract it first and make a manipulate on the number.

Thenks

Comment: Please edit your question and show us your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: The operation you want to perform can be done by applying a dot-product between the 2 elements in your height column and the 2 conversion multipliers. `[feet, inches] @ [30.48, 2.54] = feet*30.48 + inches*2.54` .. so, if you get your `'6-6'` string into a dataframe with 2 columns, all you need is a dot product with the multipliers. Check my approach for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using str functions and dot

A potentially faster way (vectorized) would be using `str` functions.

> The operation you want to perform can be done by applying a dot-product between the 2 elements in your height column and the 2 conversion multipliers.
>
> ```
> [feet, inches] @ [30.48, 2.54] = feet*30.48 + inches*2.54
> ```

1. The `str.split` breaks the string into a list.
2. Then `apply(pd.Series)` breaks the list into 2 separate columns.
3. Finally, `astype(int)` converts each of the cells to int
4. Last, `dot` performs a dot product on each row with the conversion multipliers.

```
conversions = [30.48, 2.54]
df['new'] = df['Height'].str.split('-').apply(pd.Series).astype(int).dot(conversions)
```

```
0    198.12
1    167.64
2     35.56
dtype: float64
```

---

#### Using lambda functions and dot

If you are more comfortable with lambda functions, here is the code for the same -

```
conversions = [30.48, 2.54]

df['new'] = df['Height'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(map(int, x.split('-'))).dot(conversions))
```

```
0    198.12
1    167.64
2     35.56
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good step would be to split your height column into two (feet + inches) first, and then go from there:

```
df['feet'] = df['Height'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0]))
df['inches'] = df['Height'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1]))
df['feet_in_cm'] = df['feet'] * 30.48
df['inches_in_cm'] = df['inches'] * 2.54
df['height_in_cm'] = df['feet_in_cm'] + df['inches_in_cm']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only values in the column would be strings with 3 characters (number_of_feet, '-', number_of_inches), then the solution could be something like this:

```
your_table['Height'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0])*30.48 + int(x.split('-')[1])*2.54)
```

However, as I can see from second row of your table, you have some additional characters in your strings, which might require additional preprocessing (in this case spaces, but they won't impact the code - the string should easily be changed to integer).